# delete elements from list of lists from within for-loop

Tags: r, list

I have a named list of lists (of data frames).

```
l_of_lists <- list(
  fruits = list(
      red = data.frame("apple", "cherry", "strawberry"),
      yellow = data.frame("banana", "lemon"),
      orange = data.frame("orange", "grapefruit", "blood orange")),
  colors = list(
      green = data.frame("light green", "green", "dark green"),
      red = data.frame("red", "dark red"),
      blue = data.frame("light blue", "blue", "dark blue")),
  places = list(
    inside = data.frame("living room", "bathrooom", "kitchen"),
    outside = data.frame("garden", "yard"),
    neighborhood = data.frame("playground", "shop", "school"))
  )
```

I am looping over `l_of_lists`'s `sublists` to determine the number of columns of each data frame and I want to *delete each `sublist` which does not fulfill the condition* (which in this example is that it has three columns).

with the following code:

```
for (ls in l_of_lists){
  for (sublist in ls){
    if (!ncol(sublist) == 3)
    {
      print(ncol(sublist))
      #sublist <- NULL # this does achieve the desired result
    }
  }
}
```

How can I delete the sublist I identified with the condition?
(I'm sure there is a more efficient way to accomplish this and I'm happy for hints regarding this.)

Comment: The reason this doesn't work as you expect is because the object `sublist` within the loop is not a pointer to the original object within `l_of_lists` but is actually a brand new object created and (then assigned `NULL`) within each loop cycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much easier to call you the elements which does not have 3 columns:

```
lapply(l_of_lists,function(i)i[sapply(i,length)==3])
```

With the sapply, you loop through each element of l_of_list to get a vector of number of columns. You use this to subset on those that have 3 columns.

And if you want to delete, try this

```
l_of_lists = lapply(l_of_lists,function(i)i[sapply(i,length)==3])
```

Comment: While I think this is the best solution, it does not answer the question which specifically asks about  removing items within for loops.

Comment: @rookie in R, for loops are often not the clearest or most efficient way of iterating over objects, since they miss out on R's vectorized nature. It's pretty often that an asker's attempt can be improved primarily by replacing loops with something like an `*apply` function

Comment: Hey @rookie, yes I ought to explain why it doesn't work. In the example, setting it NULL doesn't work because sublist is a new object. You need to go back to the original list, e.g, l_of_lists[[1]][[2]] <- NULL, which is your solution :) I always find it easier to subset than to delete. Hence, I gave that solution.

Comment: @camille I never said they were...I'm simply pointing out that this answer does not answer the question which wanted to know about for loops. I also said that this is a better solution than using for loops. What is confusing you?

Comment: @StupidWolf yes that would be helpful, especially to those who might come across this and be unsure as to *why* your solution is better...which by the way has nothing to do with "efficiently iterating over objects" :)

Comment: @camille also be warned that using *apply functions in no way guarantees vectorization in most cases lapply is simply a wrapper for a for loop. see here for some more info http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use loops, then it is best to use indexes rather than the objects:

```
for (i in 1:length(l_of_lists)){
  sublist = l_of_lists[[i]]
  for (j in 1:length(sublist)){
    obj = sublist[[j]]
    if (!ncol(obj) == 3)
    {
      print(ncol(obj))
      l_of_lists[[i]][[j]] <- NULL # this does achieve the desired result
    }
  }
}
```